# Какое правило пунктуации?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Подбор слов, грамматических форм и конструкций, даже звуков, ***не менее важен, чем*** предмет разговора.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Обороты, присоединяемые союзом «чем», выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми, если в предложении называются или подразумеваются два сравниваемых понятия.
В Вашем примере сравниваются подбор слов и предмет разговора, следовательно, запятая отделяет сравнительный оборот.

Однако при отсутствии сравниваемых понятий слова «(не) более / менее чем» образуют с последующими словами неразложимое сочетание (единый член предложения), не требующее постановки знаков препинания. Как правило, в этом случае после слов «(не) более / менее чем» следует количественно-именное сочетание (счетный оборот) или название единицы измерения (час, грамм, километр и т. п.).Деревня была уже не более чем в двухстах шагах… Н. Гумилев, Записки кавалериста. Совершенно больной и даже постаревший поэт не более чем через две минуты входил на веранду Грибоедова. М. Булгаков, Мастер и Маргарита. Это разговор не больше чем на двадцать минут… В. Аксенов, Новый сладостный стиль.

Можно применить такой  критерий: если оборот "(не) менее чем", "(не) более чем" и т. п. изъять и фраза не "рассыпется" – запятая не ставится; если фраза "рассыпается", или приобретает случайный смысл, или требуется запятая, то запятая ставится и перед "чем".

Подбор слов, грамматических форм и конструкций, даже звуков,... ВАЖЕН предмет разговора.- фраза рассыпалась, запятая нужна.

Деревня была уже ... в двухстах шагах… Н. Гумилев -всё нормально, запятая не нужна.